How to run indefinite loop in the background to interrupt AI voice assistant, asyncio, Python?
I'm trying to modify application for conversational agent from this github. I want to implement interruption of text-to-speech model by user.
The idea is following:
There is the class TextToSpeech with method speak that uses subprocess to play audio translated from text chunk by chunk. Befor playing each chunk of audio it's checking if interruption which is asyncio.Event is set, and if it's True than function terminates subprocess and returns:
class TextToSpeech:
    # Set your Deepgram API Key and desired voice model
    DG_API_KEY = os.getenv("DEEPGRAM_API_KEY")
    MODEL_NAME = "aura-helios-en"  # Example model name, change as needed

    @staticmethod
    def is_installed(lib_name: str) -> bool:
        lib = shutil.which(lib_name)
        return lib is not None

    def speak(self, text):
        if not self.is_installed("ffplay"):
            raise ValueError("ffplay not found, necessary to stream audio.")

        DEEPGRAM_URL = f"https://api.deepgram.com/v1/speak?model={self.MODEL_NAME}&performance=some&encoding=linear16&sample_rate=24000"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Token {self.DG_API_KEY}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
        payload = {
            "text": text
        }
       
        player_command = ["ffplay", "-autoexit", "-", "-nodisp"]
        player_process = subprocess.Popen(
            player_command,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        )

        start_time = time.time()  # Record the time before sending the request
        first_byte_time = None  # Initialize a variable to store the time when the first byte is received

        with requests.post(DEEPGRAM_URL, stream=True, headers=headers, json=payload) as r:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                if interruption.is_set():
                    player_process.kill()
                    return

                if chunk:
                    if first_byte_time is None:  # Check if this is the first chunk received
                        first_byte_time = time.time()  # Record the time when the first byte is received
                        ttfb = int((first_byte_time - start_time)*1000)  # Calculate the time to first byte
                        print(f"TTS Time to First Byte (TTFB): {ttfb}ms\n")

                    player_process.stdin.write(chunk)
                    player_process.stdin.flush()

        if player_process.stdin:
            player_process.stdin.close()
        player_process.wait()

Async function get_transcript performs speech-to-text transcription. It contains function on_message to check if received audio is user's speech and sets the interruption Event in these cases:
async def get_transcript(callback):
    try:
        # example of setting up a client config. logging values: WARNING, VERBOSE, DEBUG, SPAM
        config = DeepgramClientOptions(options={"keepalive": "true"})
        deepgram: DeepgramClient = DeepgramClient("", config)

        dg_connection = deepgram.listen.asynclive.v("1")
        print ("Listening...")

        async def on_message(self, result, **kwargs):
            sentence = result.channel.alternatives[0].transcript
            if not result.speech_final:
                transcript_collector.add_part(sentence)
                interruption.set()
                transcription_complete.clear()
            else:
                # This is the final part of the current sentence
                transcript_collector.add_part(sentence)
                full_sentence = transcript_collector.get_full_transcript()
                    
                # Check if the full_sentence is not empty before printing
                if len(full_sentence.strip()) > 0:
                    full_sentence = full_sentence.strip()
                    print(f"Human: {full_sentence}")
                    callback(full_sentence)  # Call the callback with the full_sentence
                    transcript_collector.reset()
                    transcription_complete.set()  # Signal to stop transcription and exit
        
        dg_connection.on(LiveTranscriptionEvents.Transcript, on_message)
        options = LiveOptions(
                model="nova-2",
                punctuate=True,
                language="en-US",
                encoding="linear16",
                channels=1,
                sample_rate=16000,
                endpointing=300,
                smart_format=True,
            )

        await dg_connection.start(options)

        # Open a microphone stream on the default input device
        microphone = Microphone(dg_connection.send)
        microphone.start()
       
        # start indefinite loop to listen continuously
        while not conversation_over.is_set():
            await asyncio.sleep(0.01) 

        # Wait for the microphone to close
        microphone.finish()

        # Indicate that we've finished
        await dg_connection.finish()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Could not open socket: {e}")
        return

I need to run this function in indefinite loop in the background, simultaneously with TextToSpeech().speak() to continuously listen to user and catch interruptions.
This is the class with main async function:
class ConversationManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.transcription_response = ""
        self.llm = LanguageModelProcessor()

    async def main(self):
        def handle_full_sentence(full_sentence):
            self.transcription_response = full_sentence

        asyncio.create_task(get_transcript(handle_full_sentence))

        # Loop indefinitely until "goodbye" is detected
        while not conversation_over.is_set():
            await transcription_complete.wait()
            interruption.clear()

            if not transcription_complete.is_set():
                continue
            
            # Check for "goodbye" to exit the loop
            if "goodbye" in self.transcription_response.lower():
                conversation_over.set()

            transcription_complete.clear()
            
            llm_response = self.llm.process(self.transcription_response)

            tts = TextToSpeech()

            tts.speak(llm_response)

            # Reset transcription_response for the next loop iteration
            self.transcription_response = ""

It runs with the following code:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = ConversationManager()
    asyncio.run(manager.main())

I'm creating Events outside of all functions this way:
transcription_complete = asyncio.Event()  # Event to signal transcription completion
conversation_over = asyncio.Event() # Event to signal end of conversation
interruption = asyncio.Event()  # Event to signal interruption

As I understand task asyncio.create_task(get_transcript(handle_full_sentence)) runs a function get_transcript every time await appears. It's recording and transcribing my voice in the background, because if I'm talking while TextToSpeech().speak() then after speak() returns I can see all of my transcribed phrases in the console. But the problem is that it's not interrupting the TextToSpeech().speak().
